# python pattern matching numbers

Tags: python, regex, generator

what is the best way to match numbers in python

what I trying to do?

I am reading a serial connection, the output is of the range 0 - 1023.
sometimes however I get the following string (they are read as 'str'):

```
1023
10?1023
1023
```

I am matching the output to the alphabet. 
the moment I am using:

```
input = '10?1023'
print sum(int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', input))
```

as I thought a generator would be quicker than list comprehension.
But matching would give me 1033. Ideally I would like it to return none.

any ideas?, I think I just need to work on the regrep syntax. Is there a way of excluding sum, when using generators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to cast a string to an integer, except you want `None` if it isn't one.

```
try:
    y = int(x)
except ValueError:
    y = None
```

Or if you want to sum all the integers on a single line:

```
>>> input = """1023
... 10?1023
... 1023
... """
>>> 
>>> sum(int(line) if line.isdigit() else 0 for line in input.splitlines())
2046
>>>
```

Comment: I had thought about this... but I never really understood how to use `except`! it is certainly simpler ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is matching numbers in the String, so the result is correct... it matches two groups, 10 and 1023.

If you want to make sure you have ONLY numbers, you can use something like

```
^\d+$
```

Comment: how would I match only the numbers followed by white space?

Comment: \d+\s if you only want one whitespace, or \s+ if you can have several